# how to access function parameter value inside nested AngularJS for each loop?

Tags: angularjs

I am new for AngularJS and I am trying to access function parameter value inside nested angular for each loop , but that variable gets undefined error. here is my code .

```
var pieChart = function (_data, _fieldName) {
      var data = _data;
      var cost_max = 0;
      var cost_min = 99999;

      angular.forEach(groupBy($scope.api_data, _fieldName), function (obj, index) {
          var total = 0;
          var name = '';
          angular.forEach(obj, function (row, i) {
              name = row._fieldName;
              total += 1;
          })
          data.push([name, total]);
          if (cost_max < obj.cost) cost_max = obj.cost;
          if (cost_min > obj.cost) cost_min = obj.cost;
      })
      $scope.chart.data = data;
      $scope.loaded = 1;
  }
```

row._fieldName is undefined here , what was the issue ? kindly help me.

```
  var groupBy = function (xs, key) {
      return xs.reduce(function (rv, x) {
          (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
          return rv;
      }, {});
  };
```

Comment: Your function right at the top has a variable _fieldName too, then your forEach has a variable named _fieldName, could these perhaps be interfering with the property you want (row._fieldName)? Try naming them all something unique. Also, console.log() what obj is, see if it holds the structure/properties you expect.

Comment: the function groupBy may not be returning Array of Arrays. If it is not intended to return Array of Arrays, then check the logic. Post groupBy here if you still need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second `angular.forEach` loop, you have to replace `row._fieldName` with `row[_fieldName]`.

```
angular.forEach(obj, function (row, i) {
  name = row[_fieldName];
  total += 1;
})
```

By writing `row._fieldName`, you try to get the key named `_fieldName` from object `row` instead of the real field.

[Little JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lsys9nch/)